# Django/pytest: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-django

I'm working on a Django project and using pytest for testing.
I have written a very simple test case -

```
class TestwordOfTheDay(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print("Test passed")

    def test_json_response(self):
        json_response = {
            "id": 43,
            "wordOfTheDayinHindi": "अस्पष्ट",
            "wordOfTheDayinEnglish": "ambiguous",
            "wordOfTheDayinEnglish_Usage_Example": "Everyone listened to the weather report, but the forecast was ambiguous and no one knew if it was going to be rainy or sunny today.",
            "wordOfTheDayinHindi_Usage_Example": "हर किसी ने मौसम के समाचार को सुना था, लेकिन उनका पूर्वानुमान अस्पष्ट था और कोई भी यह नहीं जान पाया कि आज बरसात होगी या धूप खिलेगी।",
            "date": "2023-10-19"
        }
        response = JsonResponse(json_response)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(json_response["id"], int))
        self.assertRegex(json_response["wordOfTheDayinHindi"], r"[ऀ-ॿ]+$")
        self.assertRegex(json_response["wordOfTheDayinEnglish"], r"^[a-zA-Z]+$")
        self.assertRegex(json_response["wordOfTheDayinEnglish_Usage_Example"], r"^.*\b" + re.escape(json_response["wordOfTheDayinEnglish"]) + r"\b.*[.?!]$")
        self.assertRegex(json_response["wordOfTheDayinHindi_Usage_Example"], r"^.*\b" + re.escape(json_response["wordOfTheDayinHindi"]) + r"\b.*[.?!]$")
        self.assertEqual(json_response["date"], str(date.today()))
```

However, when I run pytest, I encounter the following error:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Any help or guidance on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation may help you :
[Configuring Django settings](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html#configuring-django-settings)

You can :

- define an environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
- use the command line with the option --ds : `pytest --ds=test.settings`
- create a file *pytest.ini*

Comment: Please, if my answer helped you, can you consider marking it as validated ? Thank you